# Simple question about integration by substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration by substitution rule states, that if $\phi:[a,b] \rightarrow I$ and $f$ is continuous on $I$ then $$\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$$

But is it also true, that:

$$\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}p(x)g(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}p(\phi(t))g(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$$ where $p$ and $g$ are also continuous on $I$?

The proof in my opinion would be the same as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), but we would put $f(x)=p(x)g(x)$ and everything else would be the same. Am I breaking some rules here?

Comment: No you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go through the same proof a second time.  You have that
$$
\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt
$$

For **any** continuous $f$.  In other words, all that is required of $f$ is that it be a function, and that it is continuous.  So, **in particular,** let $f(x) = p(x)g(x)$ for all $x$.  This defines a function $f$, and $f$ is continuous because the product of continuous functions is continuous.  Therefore integration by substitution (above) applies, and we get directly that
$$
\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}p(x)g(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}p(\phi(t))g(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt.
$$